# SABRE Webservices TravelItineraryRead v3.5 - Refundable

Tags: sabre

Is there any element in SABRE Webservices TravelItineraryRead v3.5 that indicates a stored fare is refundable or non refundable besides parsing out text in the endorsements?

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific element to indicate whether or not the fare is refundable on the PQ.

You'd need to do that from the endorsements' string as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

TravelItineraryReadRQ API will be decommissioned; please use GetReservationRQ API instead.

Might be you will get something in the new API that indicates a stored fare is refundable or non refundable